# Angular Material Sidenav locked always opens on left

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use the angular material as follows

```
1) Have it positioned on the right  
2) When opened its locked until a close button is pressed 
3) Doesn't close when you click away from menu 
4) When open its positioned on right
```

Problem is when you specify `md-is-locked-open` it always open's on the right ?

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right" md-is-locked-open="vm.isOpen('right')">

vm.isOpen = function(navID){
    if(navID){
        return $mdSidenav(navID).isOpen();
    }
};
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put it below your main content, i.e.

```
<md-content>
</md-content>
<md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav>
```

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaxLMb